# Is there something like an if mismatch or an else loop. I need help making this JavaScript Script work

Tags: javascript

How would i get a response according to a mismatch, or possibly like an Else loop but this doesn't appear to work since i get it even if i answer the question correctly, and if maybe i could do something like and if mismatch or something. I am new to JavaScript, so i cannot solve this myself.

```
var PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
    while (PromptAnswer3 === null | PromptAnswer3 === "") 
    {
    alert("You didn't answer");
    PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
    }
if (PromptAnswer3.match(/^(tennis|bowling|baseball|soccer|basketball|football|cricket|hockey|ice|hockey|rugby|track|golf|horseracing|water polo|swimming|biking|gymnastics|cheer-leading|skiing|snowboarding|iceskating|lacrosse|surfing|archery|boxing|kayaking|diving|spelunking|fencing|karate|judo|rockclimbing|softball|volleyball|wrestling|badminton|javelin throwing|synchronized swimming|yoga|ringette)!?$/i)) 
{
alert("Haha yeah, " + PromptAnswer3 "is pretty awesome.");
}
  while (PromptAnswer3)
{
  alert("I don't think that is a sport.");
  PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
}
```

**Edit [should possibly be added as an answer]**

This is what i did to make it work. It is simple and easy. I followed some of the peoples advice on the answers and put the if statement in the loop, while (PromptAnswer3), and put an else and a break in the if so that it wouldn't loop after the first time.

```
else {
    var PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
    while (PromptAnswer3 === null | PromptAnswer3 === "") 
    {
        alert("You didn't answer");
        PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
    }
    while (PromptAnswer3)
{
if (PromptAnswer3.match(/^(tennis|bowling|baseball|soccer|basketball|football|cricket|hockey|ice|hockey|rugby|track|golf|horseracing|water polo|swimming|biking|gymnastics|cheer-leading|skiing|snowboarding|iceskating|lacrosse|surfing|archery|boxing|kayaking|diving|spelunking|fencing|karate|judo|rockclimbing|softball|volleyball|wrestling|badminton|javelin throwing|synchronized swimming|yoga|ringette)!?$/i)) 
{
    alert("Haha yeah, " + PromptAnswer3 + "is pretty awesome.");
    break;
    }
    else {
      alert("I don't think that is a sport.");
      PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another question. How would i make it so there was a maximum amount of tries on the re-prompt. I guess since i'm only 13, i need some help on this.

Comment: Please don't update your question to incorporate the answer, instead accept one of the answers below by clicking on the tick to the left of it. (If your final solution is different to all of the answers then you should post an answer yourself and accept it.)

Comment: My bad, i am new to these forums and i dont have enough rep to accept an answer, but i will when i get some more rep, and accidentally did that, after i realized i shouldn't have done it :D sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var PromptAnswer3;
while( !(PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", ""))) {
    // your regex may no work properly
    if(!/^(rugby|track|...)$/i.test(PromptAnswer3)) {
        alert("Haha yeah, " + PromptAnswer3 + "is pretty awesome.");
    }else {
        alert("I don't think that is a sport.");
        PromptAnswer3 = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First off:

```
alert("Haha yeah, " + PromptAnswer3 "is pretty awesome.");
```

should have an additional plus, no?

```
alert("Haha yeah, " + PromptAnswer3 + "is pretty awesome.");
```

That jumps out at me.

Also, your second `while(PromptAnswer3)` should be an else. So maybe something like this:

```
var PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
while (PromptAnswer3 === null | PromptAnswer3 === "") {
    alert("You didn't answer");
    PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
    if (PromptAnswer3.match(/^(tennis|bowling|baseball|...)!?$/i)) {
      alert("Haha yeah, " + PromptAnswer3 "is pretty awesome.");
    } else {
      alert("I don't think that is a sport.");
      PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
    }
}
```

I can't tell when you want to exit, but this looks like it never exits. Maybe that is your intent. Those are things that look odd to me, but I did not test it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add an `else` to your `if`

```
if ([comparison is true]) {
    // you have a match 
} else {
    // you do not
}
```

Comment: He means to change the last while loop to an else statement so that it only runs when it doesn't match the regex.

Answer (score 1):

- Your indentation style is hard to read, IMO
- Did you really want to use a *bitwise or* in your first if statement? (`|`)
- use `test` to test if a regular expression matches a string. Don't use `match` for this.
- Just invert the logic in your `while` statements.

  ```
  var PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
  while (!PromptAnswer3) {
      alert("You didn't answer");
      PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
  }

  while (!/^(tennis|bowling|baseball|soccer|basketball|football|cricket|hockey|ice|hockey|rugby|track|golf|horseracing|water polo|swimming|biking|gymnastics|cheer-leading|skiing|snowboarding|iceskating|lacrosse|surfing|archery|boxing|kayaking|diving|spelunking|fencing|karate|judo|rockclimbing|softball|volleyball|wrestling|badminton|javelin throwing|synchronized swimming|yoga|ringette)!?$/i.test(PromptAnswer3)) {
      alert("I don't think that is a sport.");
      PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
  }
  alert("Haha yeah, " + PromptAnswer3 "is pretty awesome.");
  ```

Comment: Any suggestions other than a bitwise? Im not really all familiar with javascript.

Comment: @user1067625 yes, you should just use the logical or, (`||`). See Mozilla's fine [Javascript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) for details. In the above code, however, I did away with the operator altogether, because if a value is `""`, `null`, or `0` it is equivalent to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var answer = true,
    sportsRegex = /many|options/i,
    sport = true;
do {
    var question = "Well, what sports do you like to play?";
    if (!answer)
        question = "You didn't answer\n" + question;
    else if (!sport)
        question = "I don't know that as a sport.\n" + question;
    answer = prompt(question,"");
    sport = answer.match(sportsRegex);
 } while (!sport)
 sport = sport[0]; // depends on your regex
 alert("Haha yeah, " + sport + " is pretty awesome.");
```

Such Questions are always a nice usecase for the do-while construct.